# Why youtube-dl u3m8 to react js get (cors error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video-streaming, youtube-dl, hls.js

I have a site that shows a live broadcast from youtube
Website built from reactjs and nodejs
In frontend I use video.js and hls.js, to view a live broadcast from M3U8 links, and it works for me with a sample link:
https://multiplatformf.akamaihd.net/i/multi/will/bunny/big_buck_bunny_,640x360_400,640x360_700,640x360_1000,950x540_1500,.f4v.csmil/master.m3u8
In nodejs (backEnd) I use youtube-dl model to create or get an M3U8 link, I send it to react and put it in the src value in video html tag.

react component code:

```
let videoSrc = data.url;
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
}
```

node js code:

```
let video = youtubedl(`yotubeUrl`, [])
let stream = this;
video.on('info', function (info) {
    console.log(info.url)
    stream.updateYoutubeStream(info.url) // personal function to update m3u8 url
}).on('error', err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

But he gives me a cors error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR7pk.png)
And unable to connect with me
What is the problem? And how can it be fixed?

Thank you very much